# Output identifiers in python program

Tags: python, logging, console, cygwin

I am running a python script using cygwin Terminal in Windows 7. I am able to get the output in terminal window but I am unable to find out which identifiers or data elements of the program are responsible to display output on the terminal window. I have also used checkpoints like print statement in between the programs but haven't got anything useful out of it. Anyone has any idea how I shall understand the control flow of the program? Thnx

Comment: Please post code - it is nearly impossible to diagnose exactly what you mean without your python code

Comment: I'm guessing you'll want to use multiple loggers in your script. You might find [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations) useful.

Comment: Without code or at least pseudo-code this question is too general.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave us, all I can tell you is get a good IDE and learn to use the debugger. I recommmend [eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) with the [pydev plugin](http://pydev.org/).